# Transmission 3 not recognising info hash

Tags: transmission

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04. Installed Transmission 3.
When I try to use info hash Transmission says Unrecognized URL.
In my previous Ubuntu transmission worked without fail using info hash.

What do I need to do to make Transmission work?

Thanks
Ann

Comment: Two things do you know that the app works with 22.04 and answers are not sent via email only as replies on the site.

Comment: Thanks your reply. No I dont. Its included with Ubuntu 22.04 and articles I have read suggest that it does.

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal, call open transmission followed by the hash.  What fixed it for me was:

```
transmission-gtk [hash]
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too.
I report my experience hoping it will be useful to others.

I was using Transmission version 2.94 on Linux Mint 20.3
I upgraded to Mint 21.1 and got Transmission 3.0

While with the old version I had no problem with the new 3.0 version I enter the hashes and get an error, a message appears similar to: "Transmission doesn't know how to use xxxx..."

I've always done this without any problem with the old version (file menu - "open a url")

I searched for solutions online and ended up on this page, "transmission-gtk [hash] didn't work for me..

After many failed attempts and uninstall/reinstall Transmission I gave up and installed Deluge and QBittorrent.

I only found out the next day how to fix the problem.
I searched online "convert hash to magnet" the first result is a github site "Online Magnet Link Generator"

I paste the hash there and I get a link magnet that works in Transmission 3.0.

Maybe the old 2.94 version was able to do this by itself??

Please excuse my text but English is not my native language (I use an online translator)